# Sorting in Query for MySQL database using hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I have a MySQL database includes a table named 'Task'. and I used Hibernate to map the data to the database.

it includes these fields : id, user_id, project_id, deliverable_id, activity_id, ...

When I retrieve Tasks from Db, I need to sort them by Project at first, and then by Deliverable and finally by Activty.

```
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            List<Task> tasks = (List<Task>)session.createQuery(
"from Task as t where t.user.username = :name order by t.project.key ASC").setString("name", username).list();
            orderByDeliverable(tasks);
            orderByActivity(tasks);



    private void orderByDeliverable(List<Task> tasks) {
       Collections.sort(tasks, new Comparator<Task>(){   
          public int compare(Task t1, Task t2) {
             if(t1.getProject().getId() == t2.getProject().getId()) 
               return t1.getDeliverable().getKey().compareToIgnoreCase(t2.getDeliverable().getKey());
             return 0;
          }
       });
    }

    private void orderByActivity(List<Task> tasks) {
        Collections.sort(tasks, new Comparator<Task>(){  
           public int compare(Task t1, Task t2) {
              if(t1.getProject().getId() == t2.getProject().getId()) 
             if(t1.getDeliverable().getId() == t2.getDeliverable().getId()) 
                return t1.getActivity().getKey().compareToIgnoreCase(t2.getActivity().getKey());
            return 0;
           }
       });
    }
```

As you see in the code I used two methods to sort them by deliverable and activity, but I sort them by project in the Query.

I am not good in Query writing, do you know any way that I can do all sorting stuff in the query and get the same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I just need to use this query:

```
tasks = (List<Task>)session.createQuery("from Task as t where t.user.username = :name 
order by t.project.key ASC, t.deliverable.key ASC, t.activity.key ASC")
.setString("name", username).list();
```

It worked the same for me.

Actually I looked for this solution to speed-up the application that I have developed.
I tested that which one is faster. The result was the same. It does not speed-up the application.

Comment: In terms of speed/performance the difference will totally be dependent upon the number of tasks returned.  The SQL sorting approach will perform much closer to linear so that as you deal with more results the overall performance will remain closer to the performance you see now with less results.  And even if you do not expect a lot of results to be coming back, generally speaking moving processing and memory related activities outside the JVM is never a bad idea; and especially here since SQL databases are better suited (depending on your db vendor and indexes and such) to sorting.